# Angular D3 - How to reference Component's Variable inside Element function

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have appended 5 `rect`s on my SVG and tried to bind mouseOver in each element which will alter their color fill individually when hovered.

**Problem:**
How do you call `this.d3` within calling element's function? 
<strike>I tried `this.d3.select(this)` but it will of course reference the current Angular Component</strike>
<strike>I tried `this.d3.select(this)` but `this` keyword references the current Angular Component</strike>
As mentioned by @yurzui, `this` doesn't refer to the Angular Component but instead refers to the element itself.

```
private d3: D3;

foo(): void {
    let x = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        this.svg.append('rect')
        .attr('x', x)
        .attr('y', 100)
        .styles({
            'width' : 100,
            'height' : 100,
            'fill' : '#2196F3'
        })
        .on('mouseover', this.bar);

        x += 110;
    }
}

bar(d, i) {
    // Change the color of the hovered rect
    // this is referencing the current element
    // unable to call this.d3 since this is referencing the element
    this.d3.select(this)
    .attr('fill', 'red');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it will refer to angular component? You can also use `d3.event.currentTarget` to access element

Comment: Hi @yurzui, sorry. I edited the question for other's reference. `this` keyword refers to the active angular component

Comment: Can you setup plunker?

Comment: @yurzui, I'm trying but I can't seem to setup d3 in Plunkr. Anyway, tried a few testing and found that you were right. `this` actually references the current element. My problem now is how will I be able to call `d3` that I have declared in my component. *Edited the question*